# Can not run ' Ant exec executable="zip" '

Tags: linux, ant, zip

Below is my ant script.

```
<exec executable="zip" dir="/usr/local/clo/ven/image/manual_bundle/testzip/">
    <arg value="-y"/>
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <arg value="${file.path}"/>
    <arg value="*"/>
  </exec>
```

But below error occur.

---

```
zip-image_binary:
     [exec]     zip warning: name not matched: *
     [exec]
     [exec] zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -y -r /usr/local/clo/ven/image/a.zip . -i *)
     [exec] Result: 12
```

---

My purpose is to zip all the files and directories under **/usr/local/clo/ven/image/manual_bundle/testzip/**

Comment: I think there is a `zip` task built into ant, look [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) maybe this works better. It looks like your zip call gets executed in an empty directory, so it does not find anything to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the command using your shell then the shell expands the `*` glob pattern. The zip executable doesn't expect any pattern at all but a list of files (usually provided by your shell). If you don't want to use the built-in `zip` task you can emulate that behaviour by using `apply` rather than `exec`. Something like this

```
<apply executable="zip" parallel="true" relative="true"
       dir="/usr/local/clo/ven/image/manual_bundle/testzip/">
  <fileset dir="/usr/local/clo/ven/image/manual_bundle/testzip/"/>
  <mergemapper to="${file.path}"/>
  <arg value="-y"/>
  <arg value="-r"/>
  <targetfile/>
</apply>
```

The equivalent `zip` task is a lot simpler

```
<zip destfile="${file.path}">
  <fileset dir="/usr/local/clo/ven/image/manual_bundle/testzip/"/>
</zip>
```